# About strtotime

Tags: sql, strtotime

I stored data with created datetime(Y-m-d H:i:s) using strtotime function in my database. But now I need to find those stored data by using only year value. How can i do that in php or sql query?

Answer (score 1):

This SQL will return data from 2014 only, assuming you have stored the data in a field with the datetime data type:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE datefield >= '20140101'
AND datefield < '20150101'
```